# OpenAI Embeddings API: How to change the embedding output dimension?

Tags: node.js, openai-api, azure-openai, text-embedding-ada-002

In the official OpenAI node library Create embeddings if for example using the model `text-embedding-ada-002` the embeddings returned is an array of around `1536`.

```
import {Configuration, OpenAIApi} from 'openai'

openai = new OpenAIApi(this.configuration)
const parameters= {
      model: 'text-embedding-ada-002',
      input: text,
    }
// Make the embedding request and return the result
const resp = await openai.createEmbedding(parameters)
const embeddings = embedding?.data.data[0].embedding
```

I would like to be able to limit the length of the list of embeddings returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't change the embedding output dimension.** The OpenAI Embeddings API doesn't have a parameter to control this. If you use the `text-embedding-ada-002` model, you'll always get a 1536-dimensional embedding vector (i.e., there are 1536 numbers inside).

It's pre-defined, as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/second-generation-models):

[image: Screenshot]

*Note: You don't get 1536 embeddings from the OpenAI Embeddings API. You get one(!) 1536-dimensional embedding. What you can try to do is translate the embedding you get from the OpenAI Embeddings API to a lower-dimensional space. You'll have to do it manually.*

Comment: Okay thank you, for the clarification! so if I want a Limited numbers of embeddings I will have to use some other tokenizer?

Comment: Yes, you need to use any other Python library where you have an option to choose the embedding output dimension. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-word-embedding-using-word2vec/) looks promising. Seems like you can set `vector_size`.

Comment: Is there a way to take the top n most relevant embeddings out of the 1536 in the output dimension?

Comment: @kumail You can't simply "take the top n most relevant embeddings out of the 1536". **You don't get 1536 embeddings from the OpenAI Embeddings API. You get one(!) 1536-dimensional embedding.** Anyway, what you can try to do is translate the embedding you get from the OpenAI Embeddings API to a lower-dimensional space. I edited my answer.